# VLOOKUP returning N/A because references contain "." and " " in one table, not in other

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, regex, find-and-replace, vlookup

OK

I am trying to vlookup a table but the problem is the references on one table are slightly different to the references on the other table. I can get the VLOOKUP function working, but it is returning "N/A" in many of the cases because the text is in a slightly different format:

Examples in Column 1 of each table:

Table1: A&D DRAIN SERVICES WEDNESDAY

Table2: A. AND D. DRAIN SERVICES WEDNESDAY

and

1: A. G. J. Anderson

2: AGJ Anderson

and

1: P&G Cruises

2: P & G Cruises

and

1: P.M. & H F GRAHAM AND SONS

2: PM & H F GRAHAM AND SONS

etc

In column 2 of Table 1 is a number field which I want to vlookup into the empty Column 2 of Table 2.

Is there a function in excel where you can use regex etc so that it will match each time. I am sure if I could enter, somehow into the vlookup, asterisks between all characters like:

`*A*.* *A*N*D* *D*.* *D*R*A*I*N* *S*E**R*V*I*C*E*S* *W*E*D*N*E*S*D*A*Y*`

then it would work as it wouldn't matter 1) where the spaces were 2) if there were any spaces 3) whether there was a "." after single letters in between spaces, etc. etc.

Comment: Your first example doesn't contain the same characters (& vs. AND).  There are also differences in punctuation and spacing.  The rules aren't consistent (1st example vs. mixed & and AND in the last).  Lookups, and even search and replace, won't be reliable.  Maybe explore fuzzy logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate a new column in both tables where you remove all dots and spaces and replace "&" to "AND", that will work for your examples:
`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(original_value," ",""),".",""),"&","AND")

Comment: So change everything (search terms and targets), to the same "standard", where all dots and spaces are removed and &s are replaced?  Clever.  Only suggestion: do it in duplicate columns that are used for the matching rather than modifying the original data because this will leave the original data unreadable.

Comment: This is working quite well, back in a few days after tried it on all of the data...